# Paypal express checkout // payer id

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Implementing paypal via [the express checkout api](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/#id084RM05055Z),
what would be the payerID sent by paypal for an unregistered user ?
As you now don't need an account to pay via paypal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if somebody pays via the guest checkout on the PayPal checkout page you will get the payer id back as PayPal will create it at the same time for the unregistered buyer also .

Comment: allright i was unsure. but after checking the process, that make sense